# What is the best way to get a list of all xpaths from given html in Python?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, elementtree

I am looking to get a list of all xpaths from given html in Python. My current implementation only provides me with relative xpaths using the lxml library. I need the xpaths to use ids and other attributes so I can use these xpaths inside Java Selenium on another application.

```
    for element in html.iter():
        try:
            self.listOfXpathsFound.append(tree.getelementpath(element))
        except ValueError as val:
            count = count + 1
            print("ValueError: " + str(val))
            self.errorsDict["ValueError " + str(count)] = str(val)
```

I cant figure out how to get the xpaths without them being relative. Any ideas?

**Example:**

Xpath given with lxml etree: //body//p//

Required xpath: //@id="para-one"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to generate absolute XPath expressions for elements in an HTML document using lxml in Python. Absolute XPath expressions include attributes like @id to uniquely identify elements.

```
from lxml import html

# Parse your HTML document
html_content = "<your HTML content here>"
tree = html.fromstring(html_content)

# Get all elements with an "id" attribute
elements_with_id = tree.xpath('//*[@id]')

absolute_xpaths = []
for element in elements_with_id:
    # Construct the XPath with @id
    xpath = f'//*[@id="{element.get("id")}"]'
    absolute_xpaths.append(xpath)

for xpath in absolute_xpaths:
    print(xpath)
```

Comment: This is almost what I need. Only issue now is if there are multiple cases of the same id or class name being used. How can I get them all.

Comment: `//*` means all/any element so if looking for `tree.xpath('//*[@class]')` you could have many duplicates. There should be no duplicate @id though. An improvement could be `xpath = f'{tree.getpath(element)}[@id="{element.get("id")}"]'` if possible